# Get some part of string do some changes and replace it in same position

Tags: php

I have a string like `[b] [e] [h] [k] [n] [q] [t]` and i want to get `[a]` and replace it with something like `abc` and replace it in the same position. finally the out put string must be like `abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu` how can i do it thanks in advance..

Comment: I have thought to try "for" and "if" by checking each caharecter and replace it, but ot will be lenghty process. so i just leaved that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**:

```
$string = "[a] [b] [e] [h] [k] [n] [q] [t]";

$search = array('[a]', '[b]', '[e]', '[h]', '[k]');
$replace = array('abc', 'bcd', 'efg', 'hij', 'klm');

$string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);

echo $string
```

**Output:**

```
abc bcd efg hij klm [n] [q] [t]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$output = str_replace("[a]", "abc", "[a][b] [e] [h] [k] [n] [q] [t]");

// out puts abc[b] [e] [h] [k] [n] [q] [t]
```